# Create and display content from repeating Wordpress meta-box

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I have researched and followed many tutorials on how to create meta-boxes from scratch, and I have created a working repeating meta-box using the helpful code from this post: [Creating a "repeater meta-box" without a Plugin in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653777/creating-a-repeater-meta-box-without-a-plugin-in-wordpress)

However, I am getting stuck when I try to add more inputs and/or textareas. I can't get the values to save in Wordpress and I also am stuck on how to display the values on my site. It seems that there are very many tutorials on how to create the meta boxes but not how to display the content that the user saves in the meta boxes.

Here is my current code for the custom post type and repeater meta box:

```
<?php 
function llevel_create_post_expertise() {
    register_post_type( 'expertise',
        array(
            'labels'       => array(
                'name'       => __( 'Expertise' ),
            ),
            'public'       => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'has_archive'  => true,
            'supports'     => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'excerpt',
                'thumbnail',
            ), 
            'taxonomies'   => array(
                'post_tag',
                'category',
            )
        )
    );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'expertise' );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'expertise' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'llevel_create_post_expertise' );

add_action('admin_init', 'gpm_add_meta_boxes', 2);

function gpm_add_meta_boxes() {
add_meta_box( 'gpminvoice-group', 'Custom Repeatable', 'Repeatable_meta_box_display', 'page', 'normal', 'default');
}

/* Repeatable Meta Box */
function Repeatable_meta_box_display() {
    global $post;
    $gpminvoice_group = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'customdata_group', true);
     wp_nonce_field( 'gpm_repeatable_meta_box_nonce', 'gpm_repeatable_meta_box_nonce' );
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
        $( '#add-row' ).on('click', function() {
            var row = $( '.empty-row.screen-reader-text' ).clone(true);
            row.removeClass( 'empty-row screen-reader-text' );
            row.insertBefore( '#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody>tr:last' );
            return false;
        });

        $( '.remove-row' ).on('click', function() {
            $(this).parents('tr').remove();
            return false;
        });
    });
  </script>
  <table id="repeatable-fieldset-one" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <?php
     if ( $gpminvoice_group ) :
      foreach ( $gpminvoice_group as $field ) {
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td width="15%">
        <input type="text"  placeholder="Title" name="TitleItem[]" value="<?php if($field['TitleItem'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['TitleItem'] ); ?>" /></td> 
      <td width="70%">
      <textarea placeholder="Description" cols="55" rows="5" name="TitleDescription[]"> <?php if ($field['TitleDescription'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['TitleDescription'] ); ?> </textarea></td>
      <td width="15%"><a class="button remove-row" href="#1">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    else :
    // show a blank one
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="Title" title="Title" name="TitleItem[]" /></td>
      <td> 
          <textarea  placeholder="Description" name="TitleDescription[]" cols="55" rows="5">  </textarea>
          </td>
      <td><a class="button  cmb-remove-row-button button-disabled" href="#">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- empty hidden one for jQuery -->
    <tr class="empty-row screen-reader-text">
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Title" name="TitleItem[]"/></td>
      <td>
          <textarea placeholder="Description" cols="55" rows="5" name="TitleDescription[]"></textarea>
          </td>
      <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p><a id="add-row" class="button" href="#">Add another</a></p>
 <?php
}
add_action('save_post', 'custom_repeatable_meta_box_save');
function custom_repeatable_meta_box_save($post_id) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['gpm_repeatable_meta_box_nonce'] ) ||
    ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['gpm_repeatable_meta_box_nonce'], 'gpm_repeatable_meta_box_nonce' ) )
        return;

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return;

    if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id))
        return;

    $old = get_post_meta($post_id, 'customdata_group', true);
    $new = array();
    $invoiceItems = $_POST['TitleItem'];
    $prices = $_POST['TitleDescription'];
     $count = count( $invoiceItems );
     for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
        if ( $invoiceItems[$i] != '' ) :
            $new[$i]['TitleItem'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $invoiceItems[$i] ) );
             $new[$i]['TitleDescription'] = stripslashes( $prices[$i] ); // and however you want to sanitize
        endif;
    }
    if ( !empty( $new ) && $new != $old )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'customdata_group', $new );
    elseif ( empty($new) && $old )
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'customdata_group', $old );


}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: So.. what's your current code? (I suggest into types or toolset plugin; it lets you create custom fields, metaboxes, post types.. )

Comment: I edited my post to include my current code. I am trying to create it from scratch instead of using any plugins. Thanks!